# @@ERROR not set upon following error in Sybase ASE

Tags: t-sql, sap-ase

I am faced with the following error -

```
Number (213) Severity (16) State (5) Server (ASED052) Insert error: column name or number of supplied values does not match table definition.
```

and I am trying to catch it with -

```
IF @@ERROR != 0
BEGIN
-- Do stuff
END
```

However, I have found out that this error does not set the global `@@ERROR` variable. As such is the case, does anyone know of another method to catch this error?

Comment: Are you sure it proceeds after the error? in mssql Sev. 16 will terminate the batch

Comment: @AlexK. Yes it does, which is the big problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently there is no way to catch the specified error using the global `@@ERROR` variable.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using the following functions?

```
ERROR_LINE()
ERROR_MESSAGE()
ERROR_NUMBER()
ERROR_PROCEDURE()
ERROR_SEVERITY()
ERROR_STATE()
```

Or you could use a try/catch block :

```
BEGIN TRY
...
END TRY
BEGIN CATCH
...
END CATCH
```

Comment: Yes it's sometimes SYBASE :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this solution:

I. Create a procedure with the code that generates error.

```
create procedure Proc1
as
begin
  insert into tab(Fake_Column) 
  values ('aaa')
end
```

II. Run procedure Proc1 and catch error:

```
exec Proc1

IF @@error <> 0
begin
    print 'ERROR!'    
end
```

Comment: If `@@error = 0` will print when there is no error, right? Not a SYBASE guy as I proved up there tho.

Comment: @Parado, I do not wish to nest SPROCS like that. Thanks though.

Comment: @czchlong I'm not sure there is another way, It's SYBASE.